# Exit NodeJS process when spawned python script is running

Tags: python, node.js, child-process, spawn

I wanted to develop NodeJS app, that would spawn python script on start and then communicate with it via python `input` and nodejs `pyProcess.stdin.write`.

**The communication works**, but the node process does not know when to exit.

Simple NodeJS code to reproduce the issue:

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process")

let pyProcess = spawn("python", [`python/main.py`])

pyProcess.stdin.write(`doSomething(1,2,3)`)
```

Simple Python code to reproduce the issue:

```py
while True:
    command = input().strip()
    try:
        eval(command)
    except:
        print("Invalid command:", command)
```

This code will simply run forever, even there is nothing more to execute and the function `doSomething(1,2,3)` was already executed.

Here is what I have tried:

**1. Putting process listeners in the node script:**

```js
process.on("beforeExit", (e) => {
  console.log("before") // None of these gets called
})
process.on("exit", (e) => {
  console.log("onexit") // None of these gets called
})
```

Which I thought should work according to [NodeJS process documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-beforeexit).

**2. Adding some exit statement into python code:**

```py
while True:
    command = input().strip()
    if command == "exit":
        sys.exit(0)
    try:
        eval(command)
    except:
        print("Invalid command:", command)
```

But this required having line like this: `pyProcess.stdin.write("exit\n")` in the bottom of the node file.

I would like to know, if there is a way of achieving this behaviour. I am open to literally any approach. Doesn't matter if it would require some npm module or changing the python script entirely.

Thanks for help!